# How do I respond with the value of a Key in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-persistent

I'm writing a REST API for a resource in Yesod. I have a POST method that should try to create the given resource and if successful return 201 and the ID of the newly created resource. E.g.,

```
postResourceR :: Handler String
postResourceR = do
  id <- runDB $ insert Resource
  sendResponseStatus status201 id -- DOES NOT COMPILE
```

Here's the error I get, which is plain enough:

```
No instance for (ToTypedContent (Key Resource))
  arising from use of 'sendResponseStatus'
```

I know I want something of the `ToTypedContent`, but I can't find any way to get that from a `Key` in Database.Persist.Class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's the definition of the actual resource:

```
Notification
    title Text
    content Text
    icon Text Maybe
    action Text Maybe 
    created UTCTime
    updated UTCTime
    deriving Show
```

Comment: AFAIK `ToTypedContent` is basically a `ByteString`([see the Yesod book/docu](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/restful-content)) - it's a hard to tell how you could get it because we don't even know the type of your `Key`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it was relevant because i didn't explicitly define it. The definition of my resource is now added.

Comment: the concrete type will also depend on your db-backend etc. - anyway did you have a look at the yesod book I linked? Basically if you can `show` the key just `show id` should work - although I guess you sooner or later need the other direction as well

Comment: I've read the chapter, but I couldn't put it together. I see it now in the definition of `ToContent` and `ToTypedContent`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming you're using a SQL backend, you can use [fromSqlKey](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-2.0/persistent-2.1.2/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v:fromSqlKey). More generally you can use [toBackendKey](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-2.0/persistent-2.1.2/Database-Persist-Class.html#v:toBackendKey).